# Splitting lines into individual strings in Perl

Tags: perl

Here's my code currently:

```
    open (MYFILE, "text.txt"); 
    while(<MYFILE>){
        split; 
        if (m,test,){
            print $_; 
        }
    }
    close(MYFILE);
```

So if my test.txt file had the following:

```
line 1: this is a test line
line 2: this has nothing
line 3: oh here's a test
```

My output is:

```
line 1: this is a testword line
line 3: oh here's a testphrase
```

My desired output is just outputting the word with "test" in it or

```
line 1: testword
line 3: testphrase
```

I thought by using "split", it changes how Perl reads the input instead of line by line now it would be word by word but it doesn't seem to work. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: `split` is a function that returns a list of words - what did you do with that list?

Comment: I thought I was using the pattern checker on that list of words to find the word I was looking for, at least that's what I was trying to do

Comment: the `if (m/test/)` is an implicit test against `$_`, which is the line read by `<MYFILE>` and then printed. `split` doesn't have an implicit output variable.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place where people who know their craft well can come to seek the help of their peers. Expressions like `m,test,` show that you clearly have zero knowledge of Perl, and are hoping for free consultancy. You need to either learn the skill yourself or to pay someone who has spent the effort to educate themselves.

Comment: *"I thought by using "split", it changes how Perl reads the input "* Did you read *anything*? How about [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html)? How do you get your car fixed? *"Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them"* I'm not surprised.

Comment: You are right, I don't know much about Perl, I'm trying to teach myself right now and I thought this site was a good place to ask for help but I didn't realize you had to be a pro before you could ask a question. I'm sorry.

Comment: You don't have to be a "professional" but you must believe that you're capable of what you're trying to do, and you should have read and experimented a lot to try to understand the language well before asking others about your problem. You won't learn anything by guessing, or by copying what others have written and pasting it into your program. You will only have to post the new code to Stack Overflow and ask for another fix. You need to *learn the language*, and copying `split` without understanding what it does isn't making you a good programmer.

Answer (score 0):

```
open (MYFILE, "text.txt"); 
while(<MYFILE>) {
    print grep /test/, split; 
}
close(MYFILE);
```